# FreeBSD = What of Linux Dists

Tags: linux, freebsd

The main original standard version for general-purposes BSD Unix-like system is FreeBSD which is by default doesn't have installed GUI and can be installed directly in single board computer . I would like to ask about what corresponds FreeBSD in Linux distributions? Is it Linux kernel by it self?

Also, can we consider FreeBSD as a kernel ?

Comment: This got closed because it is a generic Unix question, not a question specifically about a problem experienced in the scope of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq).

Comment: I think it is better then to help the asker in migrating his question to the suitable place.

Comment: This question is essentially asking for a Product Recommendation (which Linux distro meets a specific need) which is also off-topic on all [SE] sites. Which is why I didn't migrate it to [unix.se] - a site where most basic *nix questions are acceptable. [SU] and [ubuntu.se] are also places with more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FreeBSD is a Operating System. Linux is just a Kernel. a "Linux Distribution" is the Linux kernel + GNU Userland + a bunch of Distro-specific other stuff (like package managers and more).

FreeBSD isn't the original BSD, that was 386BSD. FreeBSD's the most popular of the BSDs, but I'm not sure I'd call it the "standard" either. FreeBSD does have a kernel that can be separated from the rest of the OS, as in the case of Debian/kFreeBSD, which pairs the FreeBSD Kernel with a GNU Userland and Debian customizations. FreeBSD's Userland can also be used with a Mach kernel, as is the case with Darwin (the core OS of OSX) - with other Darwin specirfic customizations as well.

Most Linux distro have a no-GUI option, commonly called Text Mode or Headless.

A kernel with nothing else would be extremely useless. Kernels are essentially resource managers, they don't really provide much/any functionality that the end user would want. That stuff is provided by the Userland and additional software.